# Matplotlib: plot multiple individual plots in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphing

I want to plot multiple benchmarks, each on a separate plot. Here's my code:

```
for benchmark in benchmarks:
   readFile = open(benchmark+'.txt')
   text = readFile.read()
   x = re.findall(r"(\d+)",text)
   x = [int(i) for i in liveRatio]
   pylab.plot(x)
   F = pylab.gcf()
   F.savefig('benchmark',dpi=200)
```

The code plots all the data on the same plot. But, I want individual separate plots for each benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the figure before each plot call:

```
for benchmark in benchmarks:
   readFile = open(benchmark+'.txt')
   text = readFile.read()
   x = re.findall(r"(\d+)",text)
   x = [int(i) for i in liveRatio]

   #clear the figure
   pylab.clf()

   pylab.plot(x)
   F = pylab.gcf()
   F.savefig('benchmark',dpi=200)
```

On a second note each time you iterate the figure will be overwritten so I suggest something like this:

```
   F.savefig(benchmark+'.png',dpi=200)
```