# Is there a way to iterate plots in Python?

Tags: python, plot

Say I have a function `J(x,y)[x =(0,4), y= (0,20)]` and I want to make a plot with different combinations of `(x,y)` on the same plot. Is there a way to incorporate a for-loop inside the `plot()` function instead of having to solve for `J(x,y)` before plotting? I'm thinking something like `plot(for x in range(0,4)....)`.

Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to place list-comprehension inside the `plot()` function? Why?

Comment: What library are you using to do the plotting? That will determine whether what you want to do is possible.

Comment: Are you interested in real-time plotting / plot animation? If so, matplotlib has an animation API for that (http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html). Other possible options for real-time plotting are provided in this older question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib

Comment: @cricket_007, Cause the function I want to solve takes the form of J_{x}(y) and I want to run x from 0 to 100.. Currently, the only way I know how to plot in python (using pylab) is to do it one by one plot(J_{0}(y), J_{1}(y),....), and do this for x= 100 would take a long time. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @kindall, I'm using pylab. Thanks!

Comment: Related? [Multiple plot on one figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254472/multiple-plot-in-one-figure-in-python/21254861)

Comment: `pylab.plot([int(i) for x in range(0,4)])` seems to work for this SO member: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273365/matplotlib-plot-multiple-individual-plots-in-a-loop ... is this along the lines of what you are looking to do?